# android timer animation hangup after little time

Tags: java, android

i'm very new to android and i want to animate a button .what i do is change it's background between 2 colors in 100 milliseconds rapidly .but it doesn't work nicely .button's background get changed but with the time it's get stuck after at least 5 ,6 seconds it stuck and i can't see the animation and ui freeze ..

this is my relevant code..

```
    int c = Color.parseColor("#00FF00");
    int c2 = Color.parseColor("#FFFF00");

    EditText t1;
    Button b5;
    Button b6;
    boolean btf=false;


    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                //do your code here
                //also call the same runnable

                if (btf){
                   b6.setBackgroundColor(c);
                    btf=false;
                }else {
                   b6.setBackgroundColor(c2);
                    btf=true;
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            finally{
                //also call the same runnable
                handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.boad);

         b5= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
         b6= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);

          b5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                   handler.postDelayed(runable, 100);
            }
        });
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please update your handler code by this code,

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                //do your code here
                //also call the same runnable

                if (btf){
                   b6.setBackgroundColor(c);
                    btf=false;
                }else {
                   b6.setBackgroundColor(c2);
                    btf=true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

    };
```